# rails generator won't work inside my spree application.

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, generator, spree

I am trying to integrate spree into a fresh install of a rails application.  I am following along with the [getting started guide](http://guides.spreecommerce.com/getting_started.html) on spree's website.  I am at the step that tells me to call the generate command to create my Spree site.  when doing this i get an error:

```
    C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/ext/module.rb:36:in `c
onst_missing': uninitialized constant Devise::IndifferentHash (NameError)
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/spree_auth-0.40.0/lib/spree_aut
h.rb:17:in `activate'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.1.rc2/lib/act
ive_support/callbacks.rb:413:in `_run_prepare_callbacks'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.1.rc2/lib/act
ive_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.1.1.rc2/lib/action
_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:46:in `prepare!'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.1.rc2/lib/rails/ap
plication/finisher.rb:41:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.1.rc2/lib/rails/in
itializable.rb:29:in `instance_exec'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.1.rc2/lib/rails/in
itializable.rb:29:in `run'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.1.rc2/lib/rails/in
itializable.rb:54:in `block in run_initializers'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.1.rc2/lib/rails/in
itializable.rb:53:in `each'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.1.rc2/lib/rails/in
itializable.rb:53:in `run_initializers'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.1.rc2/lib/rails/ap
plication.rb:96:in `initialize!'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.1.rc2/lib/rails/ra
iltie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
        from C:/Users/Edu/workspace/my_store/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (r
equired)>'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.1.rc2/lib/rails/ap
plication.rb:83:in `require_environment!'
        from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.1.rc2/lib/rails/co
mmands.rb:22:in `<top (required)>'
        from script/rails:6:in `require'
        from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

I also get the same error if just simply run `rails g` or `rails generate` to see what generate tools i have available.

here is my gemfile for reference:

```
    source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.1.1.rc2'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails',     :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

gem 'sqlite3'

gem 'spree'

gem 'rake', '0.9.2.2'


# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.1.0'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.1.0'
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'

# To use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.0'

# Use unicorn as the web server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Deploy with Capistrano
# gem 'capistrano'

# To use debugger
# gem 'ruby-debug19', :require => 'ruby-debug'

group :test do
  # Pretty printed test output
  gem 'turn', :require => false
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `spree` version is (for some reason) set to `0.40.0`. I would recommend upgrading this to  `0.70.1`, which you can do by putting this line in your `Gemfile`:

```
gem 'spree', '~> 0.70.1'
```

**EDIT**

You mentioned that you were using Rails 3.1.1.rc2, which is something I should have noticed in the stacktrace in the question.

*Whoops.*

Anyway, when you *don't* specify a version for Spree, Bundler will attempt to resolve all the dependencies as best it can. Partly because you were using Rails 3.1.1.rc2 and partly because Spree was silly enough to specify a `>=` dependency on Rails for 0.40.0 that this problem is encountered.

Spree 0.40.0 attempts to find the *bestest* Rails  version that's `>= 3.0.3`, and `3.1.1.rc2` satisfies that criteria nicely, so it carries on.

So then *that* begs the question of "Why isn't Spree using the latest version?". That's easily explainable if you understand dependency resolution, which many people make out as hard to understand but is actually quite easy. Think computers in the 1970s.

All versions of Spree `>= 0.40.0` *do not* have Rails specified as `>= [something]`, mainly because the Spree guys wisened up here and decided that it was a silly idea. By using `>=` you mean to get all versions of a gem that are `>=` to the specified version, which includes major versions. And we all know how different Rails 2 was from Rails 3, and so we should assume Rails 3 -> Rails 4 is going to be just as "fun".

So it's only  Spree 0.40.0 that has this dependency that matches your specific (3.1.1.rc2) Rails version. There's no non-beta / RC version of Spree above that that matches that particular dependency, and so Spree 0.40.0 is used instead.

In closing, it seems that this issue would only be prevalent for people who attempting to use a version of Rails that there isn't a corresponding version of Spree out for. One way to solve this problem would be to yank the 0.40.0 gem, but that leads to its own problems, as versions before that also have the same dependency. Therefore, you should always be checking that the current version of Rails that you're using is supported by at least one Spree version.

Comment: This did the trick. Thank you! I had to set my rails gem to 3.1.1 also, because of a dependency that spree 0.70.1 has on it.  I wonder why my Spree Version 0.40.0 and Rails Version 3.1.1.Rc2 were being installed. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with rails 3.1 . The answer went put in my GEMFILE the following line.

===:git with the repository's url that works===
gem 'spree', :git => 'git://github.com/spree/spree.git'

Now it's work my generators and my spree.

greetings.